# upload a file using FTP and php

Tags: php, html, upload, ftp, filezilla

I can't Upload the file using php because i can't send the path i got from the html file to the function FTP_PUT because it only takes string "test.txt"

How Can i send the Path to this function

PHP FILE

```
$file = $_POST["file"];

// upload file
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY))
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading $file.";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

HTML FILE

```
<div class="container">
 
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
               <form class="well" action="Upload.php" method="post" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="file">Select a file to upload</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">

                   <!-- <p class="help-block">Only jpg,jpeg,png and gif file with maximum size of 1 MB is allowed.</p> -->
                  </div>
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Upload">
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I changed these 2 but still


Notice: Undefined index: file in 

upload.php on line 12

Warning: ftp_put(): Filename cannot be empty in upload.php on line 16
Error uploading .

Comment: what does  tmp_name  mean in this case ?

Comment: That is not the problem I added it but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` instead of `$_POST["file"]`

edit:

```
$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

// upload file
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $file_name, $file, FTP_BINARY))
```

or move the uploaded file first:

```
$target_path = "uploads/".basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_path);
```

Comment: It worked but the output is  C:\xampp\tmp\php7A1D.tmpSuccessfully uploaded   how to change the tmp location to the name of the uploaded file

Comment: use $target_path after moving the file to uploads or set the second parameter of ftp_put to the filename.

Comment: if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, "xxx.txt", $target_file, FTP_ASCII))

how to make the uploaded file with the same name and type of the local file ?

Comment: `if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $_FILES["file"]["name"], $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], FTP_BINARY))` or move it (see above)

Answer (score 0):

Change your form tag to :

```
<form class="well" action="Upload.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If you don't include

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Nothing will get uploaded!

Comment: i have done this . but still it's not the problem 

the problem is to get the path from the html and put in the function FTP_PUT

Answer (score 0):

Check that the path is correct... I don't know your file structure so I'm guessing you need the full path, try...

```
 if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, getcwd().$file, $file, FTP_BINARY)
```

Comment: what does BINARY mean ? why not ASCII ?

Comment: Binary in your case, if you can open the file in notepad it's ascii. If it's sound, image or a movie then it's binary